# Parse - Using a list of Pointers in beforeSave

Tags: parse-platform

I'm very new to Parse and am trying to get some logic working in my beforeSave trigger.

The History class is made up as: game, gameWinners, gameLosers

From android I'm passing an array of ParseUser Pointers for gameWinners and gameLosers.

In the log I see that the data arrives fine:

> Input: {"original":null,"update":{"ACL":{"*":{"read":true,"write":true},"k2UVtUJjDd":{"read":true,"write":true}},"game":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Games","objectId":"mTopB9RdmQ"},"gameLosers":[[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"WMpIFuNnBH"},{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"PTvaGdsyjp"}]],"gameWinners":[[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"Re1llgmbwi"}]],"submitter":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"k2UVtUJjDd"}}}

But calling `request.object.get("gameWinners")` I get:

> [{"objectId":"Re1llgmbwi"},{"objectId":"WMpIFuNnBH"}]

What happened to the Pointer type? I just now have objectId's and when using them in a `containedIn` query, I get the error

> pointer field player needs a pointer value

beforeSave code snippet that fails with the `containedIn` statement:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("History", function(request, response) {
if(request.object.get("game") === null)
    response.error("Game name was not specified");
else {
    // Get Ratings of all gameWinners
    var gameWinnerRatingsQuery = new Parse.Query("Ratings");
    gameWinnerRatingsQuery.equalTo("game", request.object.get("game"));
    gameWinnerRatingsQuery.containedIn("player", request.object.get("gameWinners"));
    gameWinnerRatingsQuery.find({
```

I should mention that the Ratings Class is setup so that game is a Pointer and player is a Pointer as well. The single game Pointer passed from Android works fine, I'm just not understanding how to apply the list of Pointers.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Underscore` map function, build an array of User objects for all the winners:

```
 var winnersList = _.map(request.object.get("gameWinners"), function(winner) {
    var playerObject = new Parse.User();
    playerObject.id = winner.id;
    return playerObject;
}
```

Then use the player list in your constraint:

```
gameWinnerRatingsQuery.containedIn("player", winnersList);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot when I get home tonight. I was trying something similar but was using '.objectId' instead of '.id' as that looked to be what the field was called.